# How to add Qvideowidget to second mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt

```
void Qvideomedia::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QVideoWidget* vw = new QVideoWidget();

    QMediaPlayer* mp = new QMediaPlayer(vw);

    QString vidstring = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Select video file", QDir::homePath());

    mp->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(vidstring));
    mp->setVideoOutput(vw);
    vw->setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500);
    vw->show();
    mp->play();
}
```

Am having two classes one contain the main window while the other also has it own window,  whenever I play the video the Qvideowiget has it own window, I want to display the QVideowidget inside the second windows, but all my effect has not been fruitful... thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the issue you have.

Comment: I mean I want to add the Qvideowidget to a window, but the window I want to add it to isn't the mainwindow..

Comment: i can add the Qvideowidget to the Mainwindow but i cant add it to a subwindow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the QVideowidget the child of your second window.
Check out this code just added a line to your code

```cpp
void Qvideomedia::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QVideoWidget* vw = new QVideoWidget();

    QMediaPlayer* mp = new QMediaPlayer(vw);

    QString vidstring = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Select video file", QDir::homePath());

    mp->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(vidstring));
    mp->setVideoOutput(vw);
    vw->setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500); // you will have to change this 
    vw->setparent(this);  // this is  what you need ..
    vw->show();
    mp->play();
}
```